# Codeigniter Model: summary, join, group by in multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm using Codeigniter, what I want to summary total qty and group by id_user:

TABLE 1: user_table

```
user_ID |  name    |
------  | ------   |
   1    |  John    |
   2    |  Frank   |
   3    |  Jesse   |
   4    |  Patrick |
   5    |  Lucy    |
```

TABLE 2: sales_table

```
sales_ID | user_ID | qty |
 ------  | ------  | ----- |
    1    | 1       |  23   |
    2    | 1       |  11   |
    3    | 2       |  10   |
    4    | 4       |  8    |
    5    | 3       |  14   |
    6    | 5       |  15   |
    7    | 3       |  7    |
```

Result:

```
   No    |  Name   | total qty |
 ------  | ------  | --------- |
    1    |  John   |    34     |
    2    |  Frank  |    10     |
    4    |  Patrick|    8      |
    5    |  Jesse  |    21     |
    6    |  Lucy   |    15     |
```

How can I do this result with CodeIgniter in my model and controller?
Somebody please help me?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: The question probably belongs to the sql family not php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$sql="SELECT ut.user_ID as No, SUM(st.qty) as total_qty , ut.name FROM sales_table st INNER JOIN user_table ut ON ut.user_ID = st.user_ID";
$query  = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result();
print_r($result);
```

OR

```
$this->db->select('ut.user_ID as No, SUM(st.qty) as total_qty , ut.name');
$this->db->from('sales_table st');
$this->db->join('ser_table ut', 'ut.user_ID = st.user_ID');
$query  = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows (but you are mean't to provide what you have tried rather than expect people to do it for you :o))

```
SELECT ut.`name`,SUM(st.qty) as `total_qty`
FROM user_table ut
LEFT JOIN sales_table st USING (user_ID)
GROUP BY ut.user_ID
```

Here is how this would look in Codeigniter:

```
$db = $this->db;

$db->select('ut.name,SUM(st.qty) as total_qty');
$db->join('sales_table st','user_ID','left');
$db->group_by('ut.user_ID');

$data = $db->get('user_table ut')->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, sum(qty) as total_qty FROM sales_table 
LEFT JOIN user_table ON user_table.user_ID = sales_table.user_ID
GROUP BY sales_table.user_ID
```